# Node.js Error throwing known as bad practice, yet essential for TDD

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, coding-style, tdd

I've heard from plenty of people saying that throwing errors in Node is bad practice, and you should rather manually handle them via CommonJS's callback syntax:

```
somethingThatPassesAnError( function(err, value) {
    if (err) console.log("ERROR: " + err);
});
```

Yet, I've found in multiple unit testing frameworks (Mocha, Should.js, Gently) that it seems like they *want* you to `throw` an error when something happens. I mean, sure, you can design your tests to check for equality of variables and check for not-null in error vars, but in the words of Ryan Dahl himself, "you should write your framework to make the right things easy to do and the wrong things hard to do".

So what gives? Can anyone explain why that practice exists? Should I start throwing fatal exceptions like `require()` would if the module couldn't be found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It because nodejs programs typically make heavy use of async, and as a result errors are often thrown after your try/catch has already completed successfully.  Consider this contrived example.

```
function foo(callback) {
  process.nextTick(function() {
    if (something) throw "error";
    callback("data");
  });
}

try {
  foo(function(data) {
    dosomething(data);
  });
} catch (e) {
  // "error" will not be caught here, as this code will have been executed
  // before the callback returns.
}
```

The typical node pattern, of the first argument in a callback being an error, obviates this problem, providing a consistent way to return errors from asynchronous code.

```
function foo(callback) {
  process.nextTick(function() {
    if (something) return callback("error");
    callback("data");
  });
}

foo(function(error, data) {
  if (error) return handleError(error);
  dosomething(data);
});
```

Comment: Yes I understand why you'd want to use the CJS styling for callbacks in the event loop, but my question is why would we have throw functionality in the first place? Is there a way to styleize the console.log() to show significance to error objects? Is there any way to throw errors asynchronously? Is there any way to catch said thrown errors asynchronously for testing frameworks so that you can test for errors with an async lib just as well as a sync lib?

Comment: Why do you need to raise errors to test for them?  Why not simply test for the returned error rather than the thrown & caught error?  The way to "throw" errors asynchronously is by using the CJS pattern.  And for synchronous bits of code, throw/catch is as useful as it ever was.  There's no reason not to use it situationally.

Comment: Because then in your testing suite you'd have to place error catching tests deep inside the callbacks while with sync. code you could place the whole chunk of code inside a should.throw()/should.not.throw(). It's a matter of being able to look from the outside vs. having to look on the inside. Call me lazy, but I think it would make testing / error handling way more consistent.

Comment: For TDD, you might call that a sign that you need more granular tests: unit tests for the different callbacks, and mocks/stubs for them when testing other parts of your app.

Answer (score 2):

It is my understanding that the case against throwing exceptions in JavaScript is due to the heavy use of asynchronous patterns.  When an error occurs on another stack, you can't catch it.  In those cases, use the `err` parameter as the first parameter for the callback.

I don't think that is the same as saying "never throw anything".  If I have synchronous code, and an exception occurs, I throw it.  There are differing opinions, but if callbacks aren't involved at all, I see no reason to not use `throw`.

Comment: See that's where I'm feeling things to be somewhat inconsistent - the sync vs. async styles are fairly similar: error handling is done in the block of code that recieves the result, and the error is generated in the block that returns the result. Like with the CJS, the error is passed to the callback but generated in caller. For sync code, you normally test to see if the result is an `instanceOf` Error. What gets me, though, is that if you choose to `throw` an Error in the sync code, it would be inconsistent with async - you'd have to just throw the Error rather than pass it as the first arg.

Comment: If I write a function that is supposed to return something, I never return an error.  I throw exceptions when exceptional things happen.  That's my philosophy... there are certainly others.  To me, it just makes sense.  I also agree with using the `err` parameter on a callback.  I just don't see the point in not throwing, if you aren't using callbacks.

Comment: Do you know of a way to "fake" throwing an error in an acync library so that it's consistent with try .. catch blocks? maybe by wrapping the try/catch on the callback attached to the event-loop itself? That way the exception will be caught in time?

Comment: No... not sure why you would want to do that, or how it would even work.  You could do what Node.js libs do internally, where if an error event isn't handled, it goes up the stack.

Comment: Yeah see that's what I'm saying. I'm not sure. I'm going to look into it. I heard that throwing an error vs. passing it might cause a performance hit. The main reason why I'd want to have throw functionality in an async. block is for TDD purposes - allowing me to test the whole block to see if it threw rather than having to test the internally passed error for equality of some value. It just makes code clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to follow the guidance on [Joyent's Error Handling in Node.js](https://www.joyent.com/node-js/production/design/errors) for this one. The oversimplified gist is that there are really two types of errors (operational and programmer), and three ways to pass errors (emitting an error event on an event emitter, returning the callback with the error argument as non-null, and throwing the error).

Operational errors are errors that you expect might happen and are able to handle, ie. not necessarily bugs. Programmer errors are errors in the code itself. If you are writing code and you expect the error, then any of the patterns for passing an error are valuable. For example:

- If the error happens inside an asynchronous function that accepts a callback, using the idiomatic return callback(new Error('Yadda yadda yadda')) is a correct solution (if you can't handle the error in the function).
- If the error happens inside of a synchronous function and is a breaking problem (ie. the program cannot continue without the operation that was attempted) then blowing up with an uncaught thrown error is acceptable.
- If the error occurs in a synchronous function but can be dealt with, then the error should be dealt with, otherwise it should be thrown, and maybe the parent function can handle it, maybe not.

Personally, I tend to only throw errors that I consider fatal, thus my code is mostly devoid of try/catch blocks (I even wrap JSON.parse in a function defined thusly: function jsonParseAsync(json, cb) { var out, err; try { out = JSON.parse(json) } catch(e) { err = e }; return cb(err, out); } ). I also try to avoid promises because they conflate promise rejection and thrown errors (even though this is getting harder to do as promises become more ubiquitous). Instead, I tend to think of synchronous functions as mathematical proofs in that if they are correct they must always be correct (thus an error in a synchronous function should break the whole program, otherwise the proof can be wrong but still usable). My error creation and checks are almost entirely assertions for bad input and emitting error events or handling asynchronous errors idiomatically.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using exceptions to handle critical errors, much like the way require() works. If this functionality causes Node.js to misbehave, then that's a bug which I'm sure will get fixed in time.

Comment: `throw` doesn't cause Node.js to misbehave.  It's not about bugs in Node.js... more of a stylistic question.